# What is the need or benefit to use an instance variable/function attribute to implement memoization vs passing down the memo in each call?

Tags: python, dynamic-programming, memoization

In a lot of examples of memoization, I see it most commonly that people favor making a wrapper or decorator (or some language-dependent variation of this, such as using a higher-order function to close over a memo object) to store the results of previous function calls in an almost 'state-like' fashion.  Such an example can be seen below:

```
class Memoize(object):
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func
        self.cache = {}
    def __call__(self, *args):
        if args in self.cache:
            return self.cache[args]
        ret = self.func(*args)
        self.cache[args] = ret
        return ret

@Memoize
def fib(n):
    if n < 2:
        return 1
    return fib(n-2) + fib(n-1)
```

What is the difference / tradefoff between doing things this way, vs simply passing down a memo in the arguments of your function?  For example, like so:

```
def fib(n, memo = {}):
    if (n < 2):
        return 1
    if (n in memo):
        return memo[n]
    memo[n] = fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2)
    return memo[n]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Separation of concerns: you don't want to muddy your nice clean implementation of `fib` with all the bookkeeping required to make it more efficient. Let `fib` compute Fibonacci numbers, and let `Memoize` worry about memoizing `fib` (or any other function).